# The expression буфетный мужик

Tags: лексикон

In *[Смерть Ивана Ильича](https://ilibrary.ru/text/7/p.1/index.html)* by Leo Tolstoy, we have the expression буфетный мужик.
I have several related questions:

1. I remember that in some lesson, I said "мужик" to mean "a (19th century) farmer" (or a "peasant" without any pejorative connotation - my English is too bad to have a clear distinction between the two words) and my professor told me that I should never say that: it's pejorative and I should only say "крестьянин". But I know that Tolstoy had no disdain at all towards farmers. So, was the pejorative connotation added later on or was there already this distinction between мужик and крестьянин in the 19th century?
2. In that story, the character doesn't work as a farmer (he works in the city), so it seems here that мужик doesn't mean "farmer" or "peasant" here but merely "someone who was born in the country". Is it the case that this word has both meanings?
3. Finally, it seems weird to me that the word буфетный should describe a human according to this definition:  ["связанный, соотносящийся по значению с существительным буфет"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Буфет* (in fancy private houses) was a small room between the dining room and the kitchen, used to decorate the meals and store them before serving. It was often also used to store hard liquor.

*Буфетчик* was a person whose duty it was to oversee the dinner service. In bigger houses, he would manage the footmen (*лакеи*); in smaller ones (like that of Ivan Ilyich), he would personally wait during the dinner, and also perform other duties around the house.

*Буфетный мужик* seems to be just the way Tolstoy refers to *буфетчик*.

In general, *мужик* meant "a man of the peasant class (*крестьянское сословие*)". The word itself didn't have any particular negative connotations apart from those that people would generally associate with the lower classes. However, most people were very sensitive about their social status, so calling someone who was not a peasant *мужик* would be taken as an insult. Tolstoy's Gerasim had been born in the country, and this fact was alluded to in the plot several times.

In imperial Russia, everyone belonged to one of several legally defined classes (*сословия*), with different legal obligations and taxation requirements. Transfer between classes was not impossible, but legally moving even between lower classes, like from a peasant to a city proletarian (*мещанин*) was a very complicated and tedious process, and wasn't always financially beneficial to boot. Most peasants who worked in towns and cities remained peasants on paper (it was called [отходничество](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)). In all likelihood, a real-life Gerasim would be an *отхожий крестьянин* as well.